# Strange Password_Hash Issue

Tags: php, php-password-hash

So im using the exact same script as I used to a while back and for some reason when I move to my new domain and hosting it is having really weird issues, I created a user and got hm to try login, It wasnt working for him I got a new hash from a random test.php file with this php:

```
<?php
/**
 * In this case, we want to increase the default cost for BCRYPT to 12.
 * Note that we also switched to BCRYPT, which will always be 60 characters.
 */
$options = [
    'cost' => 9,
];
echo password_hash("His Pass", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
?>
```

It then worked, He logged in fine and I then tried to login to my main admin account and for some reason its now not working even when I try remaking the hash 2 times now.

I have no idea whats going on can someone please enlighten me.

Heres the login code:

```
//If User Submits Form continue;
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

    //If the captcha wasn't submitted;
    if(empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

        //And theres already a try with there IP;
        if($trycount != '0') {

            //Increment there try count and give a notification;
            updateTries(); ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">localStorage.setItem("notification", "nocaptcha");</script> <?php

        //If there isn't a try on there IP yet;
        } else {

            //Add one try and give a notification;
            addTry(); ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">localStorage.setItem("notification", "nocaptcha");</script> <?php

        }

    //If the captcha was submitted;
    } else {

        //Set captcha variable to the Submitted Captcha Response;
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

        //Captcha Verification Url;
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=t&response=';

        //JSON Encode the Captcha's response and Site IP;
        $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url.urlencode($captcha).'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);

        //If the captcha wasn't verified;
        if($response['success'] == false) {

            //And theres already a try with there IP;
            if($trycount != '0') {

                //Increment there try count and give a notification;
                updateTries(); ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">localStorage.setItem("notification", "captchafailed");</script> <?php

            //If there isn't a try on there IP yet;
            } else {

                //Add one try and give a notification;
                addTry(); ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">localStorage.setItem("notification", "captchafailed");</script> <?php

            }

        //Otherwise if it was verified;
        } else {

            //Try log in with the given details;
            user_login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

            //If logged in redirect and give a notification;        
            if(loggedin()) { ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">localStorage.setItem("notification", "loggedin");</script>
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://gameshare.io'" /> <?php
            } else {

                //And theres already a try with there IP;
                if($trycount != '0') {

                    //Increment there try count and give a notification;
                    updateTries(); ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">localStorage.setItem("notification", "loginfailed");</script> <?php

                //If there isn't a try on there IP yet;
                } else {

                    //Add one try and give a notification;
                    addTry(); ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">localStorage.setItem("notification", "loginfailed");</script> <?php

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

User_login function:

```
//Create a new function named user_login;
function user_login($username = false, $password = false) {

    //Fetch for the username and password applied;
    $st = fetch("SELECT username,password,email,image FROM users WHERE username = :username",array(":username"=>$username));

    //If a row was found continue
    if($st != 0) {

        $storedhash = $st[0]['password'];

        if (password_verify($password, $storedhash)) {

            //Set a new username session and set it the username;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $st[0]['email'];
            $_SESSION['image'] = $st[0]['image'];

            if($username == 'admin') {
                $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['role'] = 'user';
            }

        }

    }

    //If no errors happened Make the $valid true;
    return true;

    $dontaddtry = true;

}
```

Fetch function:

```
//Create a new function named fetch;
function fetch($sql = false,$bind = false,$obj = false) {

    //Prepare The SQL Query;
    $query = Connect()->prepare($sql);

    //Execute Binded Query;
    $query->execute($bind);

    //While Fetching Results;
    while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        //Add a row to the results respectiveley;
        $row[] = $result;

    }

    //If there are no rows;
    if(!empty($row)) {

        //Make it an object;
        $row = ($obj)? (object) $row : $row;
    } else {

        //Else row is false;
        $row = false;
    }

    //If no errors happened Make $row true;
    return $row;

}
```

Connect Function:

```
//Create a new function named LoggedIn, And apply database info;
function Connect($host = 'localhost',$username = 'x',$password = 'x',$dbname = 'x') {

    //Try execute the PHP with no errors;
    try {

        //Create a PDO Session;
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        //Session Attributes;
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    }

    //Catch all PDOException errors;
    catch (PDOException $e) {

        //If any errors print result;
        echo "<code><pre>".print_r($e)."</pre></code>";

        //Make the PDO session false;
        $con = false;
    }

    //If no errors happened Make the PDO session true;
    return $con;
}
```

P.S If you wish to get an account to try on my site let me know and ill make a temporary account.

Comment: Is the hash correct in the database or is it an empty string? What is the column type used to store the hash?

Comment: Its correct of course and it is Varchar(60).

Comment: It's kind of hard to pinpoint an exact problem with so much code and debugging hashes can be tricky because you have no idea if it's right or not. Just an idea: why not **temporarily** switch your code store your password in plain text, execute the update thingamajig, then make sure it's actually storing the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your the php version of your new hosting. `password_hash` needs at-least `PHP 5.5.0`.

You can check your current PHP version via following code.

```
<?php
    echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
?>
```

Comment: Yes ofc im 5.6 it wouldnt work half the time otherwise.